# Navsat node not publishing to odometry in ROS

Tags: ros2, navsat-transform

A friend and I have been trying to get a GPS system integrated into an automated robot, and the GPS fix is publishing, and sending data to the navsat_transform node. We're also sending it odometry data and we're publishing IMU data through the commandline because we don't have an IMU set up at the moment. We've tried to also tried sending static transforms between different frame IDs. Although We're still not getting anything coming out of the navsat node. Also, I'm working in ROS2 on Ubuntu 22.04

Here's our launch file(spacing got messed up posting):

```
import launch
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration
import launch_ros
import os
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
pkg_share = launch_ros.substitutions.FindPackageShare(package='red_robot_sdp').find('red_robot_sdp')
default_model_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'src/description/red_robot_description.urdf')
default_rviz_config_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'rviz/urdf_config.rviz')
robot_localization_file_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'params/ekf_with_gps.yaml') 
#use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')

robot_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
    package='robot_state_publisher',
    executable='robot_state_publisher',
    parameters=[{'robot_description': Command(['xacro ', LaunchConfiguration('model')])}]
)
joint_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
    package='joint_state_publisher',
    executable='joint_state_publisher',
    name='joint_state_publisher',
    arguments=[default_model_path],
    condition=launch.conditions.UnlessCondition(LaunchConfiguration('gui'))
)
joint_state_publisher_gui_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
    package='joint_state_publisher_gui',
    executable='joint_state_publisher_gui',
    name='joint_state_publisher_gui',
    condition=launch.conditions.IfCondition(LaunchConfiguration('gui'))
)
rviz_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
    package='rviz2',
    executable='rviz2',
    name='rviz2',
    output='screen',
    arguments=['-d', LaunchConfiguration('rvizconfig')],
)

start_navsat_transform_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
    package='robot_localization',
    executable='navsat_transform_node',
    name='navsat_transform',
    output='screen',
    parameters=[robot_localization_file_path],
    remappings=[
            ('imu/data', 'imu/data'),
                ('gps/fix', '/gps/fix'), 
                ('gps/filtered', 'gps/filtered'),
                ('odometry/gps', 'odometry/gps'),
                ('odometry/filtered', 'odometry/global')
                ]
)
# Start robot localization using an Extended Kalman filter...map->odom transform
start_robot_localization_global_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
    package='robot_localization',
    executable='ekf_node',
    name='ekf_filter_node_map',
    output='screen',
    parameters=[robot_localization_file_path],
    remappings=[('odometry/filtered', 'odometry/global') #add in comma for /set_pose
                #('/set_pose', '/initialpose')
                ]
)

# Start robot localization using an Extended Kalman filter...odom->base_footprint transform
start_robot_localization_local_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
    package='robot_localization',
    executable='ekf_node',
    name='ekf_filter_node_odom',
    output='screen',
    parameters=[robot_localization_file_path],
    remappings=[('odometry/filtered', 'odometry/local'),
                #('/set_pose', '/initialpose')
                ]
 )
 

return launch.LaunchDescription([
    launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='gui', default_value='True',
                                        description='Flag to enable joint_state_publisher_gui'),
    launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='model', default_value=default_model_path,
                                        description='Absolute path to robot urdf file'),
    launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='rvizconfig', default_value=default_rviz_config_path,
                                        description='Absolute path to rviz config file'),
    joint_state_publisher_node,
    joint_state_publisher_gui_node,
    robot_state_publisher_node,
    rviz_node,
    start_navsat_transform_node,
    start_robot_localization_local_node,
    start_robot_localization_global_node,
    
    
    #Node(
     #   name='rplidar_composition',
      #  package='rplidar_ros',
       # executable='rplidar_composition',
        #output='screen',
        #parameters=[{
         #   'serial_port': '/dev/ttyUSB1',
          #  'serial_baudrate': 115200,  # A1 / A2
            # 'serial_baudrate': 256000, # A3
           # 'frame_id': 'laser',
            #'inverted': False,
            #'angle_compensate': True,
            #'scan_mode': 'Boost',
       # }],
    #),
    
    #Node(
     #       package='rf2o_laser_odometry',
      #      executable='rf2o_laser_odometry_node',
       #     name='rf2o_laser_odometry',
        #    output='screen',
         #   parameters=[{
          #      'laser_scan_topic' : '/scan',
           #     'odom_topic' : '/odom_rf2o',
            #    'publish_tf' : True,
             #   'base_frame_id' : 'base_link',
              #  'odom_frame_id' : 'odom',
               # 'init_pose_from_topic' : '',
                #'freq' : 20.0}],
        #),
])
```

And here's our parameters for the navsat nodes:

```
### ekf config file ###
ekf_filter_node_odom:
ros__parameters:

    use_sim_time: true
    frequency: 30.0
    sensor_timeout: 0.1
    two_d_mode: true
    transform_time_offset: 0.0
    transform_timeout: 0.0
    print_diagnostics: true
    debug: false

# Defaults to "robot_localization_debug.txt" if unspecified. Please specify the full path.
    debug_out_file: /home/sdp12/sdp8_ws/red_robot_sdp/robot_localization_debug.txt

# Whether to broadcast the transformation over the /tf topic. Defaults to true if unspecified.
    publish_tf: true

# Whether to publish the acceleration state. Defaults to false if unspecified.
    publish_acceleration: false

# If the filter sees a jump back in time, the filter is reset (convenient for testing with rosbags!)
    reset_on_time_jump: true

    map_frame: map                   # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
    odom_frame: odom                 # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
    base_link_frame: base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
    world_frame: odom                 # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified
    odom0: odom
    odom0_config: [true, true, true,
                   false, false, false,
                   true,  true,  true,
                   false, false, true,
                   false, false, false]

    #        [x_pos   , y_pos    , z_pos,
    #         roll    , pitch    , yaw,
    #         x_vel   , y_vel    , z_vel,
    #         roll_vel, pitch_vel, yaw_vel,
    #         x_accel , y_accel  , z_accel]

    odom0_queue_size: 2

    odom0_nodelay: false
    odom0_differential: false
    odom0_relative: false
    odom0_pose_rejection_threshold: 5.0
    odom0_twist_rejection_threshold: 1.0

    imu0: imu/data
    imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                  true,  true,  true,
                  false, false, false,
                  true,  true,  true,
                  true,  true,  true]

    #        [x_pos   , y_pos    , z_pos,
    #         roll    , pitch    , yaw,
    #         x_vel   , y_vel    , z_vel,
    #         roll_vel, pitch_vel, yaw_vel,
    #         x_accel , y_accel  , z_accel]
    
    imu0_nodelay: false
    imu0_differential: false
    imu0_relative: true
    imu0_queue_size: 7
    imu0_pose_rejection_threshold: 0.8                 # Note the difference in parameter names
    imu0_twist_rejection_threshold: 0.8                #
    imu0_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold: 0.8  #
    imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true
    use_control: false
    stamped_control: false
# The last issued control command will be used in prediction for this period. Defaults to 0.2.
    control_timeout: 0.2
# Which velocities are being controlled. Order is vx, vy, vz, vroll, vpitch, vyaw.
    control_config: [true, false, false, false, false, true]
# Places limits on how large the acceleration term will be. Should match your robot's kinematics.
    acceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.4]
# Acceleration and deceleration limits are not always the same for robots.
    deceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.5]
    acceleration_gains: [0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9]
# If your robot cannot instantaneously reach its deceleration limit, the permitted change can be controlled with these
# gains
    deceleration_gains: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
    
    process_noise_covariance: [0.05,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.05,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.06,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.06,   0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.025,   0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.025,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.04,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.01,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.02,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.015]
                               
    initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     1e-9,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     1e-9,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    1e-9]

ekf_filter_node_map:
ros__parameters:

use_sim_time: true


frequency: 30.0
sensor_timeout: 0.1
two_d_mode: true
transform_time_offset: 0.0
transform_timeout: 0.2
print_diagnostics: true
debug: true
debug_out_file: /home/sdp12/sdp8_ws/red_robot_sdp/ekf_debug.txt

# Whether to broadcast the transformation over the /tf topic. Defaults to true if unspecified.
publish_tf: True #Set to false for use w/ slam


# If the filter sees a jump back in time, the filter is reset (convenient for testing with rosbags!)
reset_on_time_jump: true

map_frame: map
odom_frame: odom
base_link_frame: base_link
world_frame: map #map or odom

odom0: odometry/gps
odom0_config: [true,  true,  false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false]
odom0_queue_size: 10
odom0_nodelay: false
odom0_differential: false
odom0_relative: false

imu0: imu/data
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              true,  true,  true,
              false, false, false,
              true,  true,  true,
              true,  true,  true]
imu0_nodelay: false
imu0_differential: false
imu0_relative: false
imu0_queue_size: 7
imu0_pose_rejection_threshold: 0.8                 # Note the difference in parameter names
imu0_twist_rejection_threshold: 0.8                #
imu0_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold: 0.8  #
imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

use_control: false

process_noise_covariance: [0.05,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.05,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.06,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.06,   0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.025,   0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.025,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.04,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.01,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.02,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,    0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,
                           0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.015]

initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     1e-9,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     1e-9,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    1e-9]



navsat_transform:
ros__parameters:
use_sim_time: true
frequency: 10.0
delay: 3.0
magnetic_declination_radians: 0.093084220955  
yaw_offset: 1.5707963 # if IMU reads 0 when facing magnetic north instead of east then set parameter to pi/2
zero_altitude: true
broadcast_cartesian_transform: true
broadcast_cartesian_transform_as_parent_frame: true
#broadcast_utm_transform: true
publish_filtered_gps: false
use_odometry_yaw: false
wait_for_datum: false
```

And our rqt graph:
[image: graph]

Answer (score 0):

Hi your configuration file is wrong:

1- You must use the **output topic (/odometry/local )** of ekf_filter_node_odom node (which is the fusion of odometry + Imu data) to feed the ekf_filter_node_map:

that being said replace this row:

```
odom0: odometry/gps
```

for this:

```
 odom0: /odometry/local # = "fused odometry + Imu in previous node"
```

2- In addition, you **cannot send IMU data** twice to the ekf_filter_node_map node(it is being already used when you fused imu+odom in ekf_filter_node_odom), as I see in your rqt chart. remove this block of code:

```
imu0: imu/data
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              true,  true,  true,
              false, false, false,
              true,  true,  true,
              true,  true,  true]
imu0_nodelay: false
imu0_differential: false
imu0_relative: false
imu0_queue_size: 7
imu0_pose_rejection_threshold: 0.8                 # Note the difference in parameter names
imu0_twist_rejection_threshold: 0.8                #
imu0_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold: 0.8  #
imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true
```

And write this in replacement ( I have used **"gps"** since it is the name of how I've configured the plugin on my urdf) :

```
odom1: gps #odometry/gps # try gps if not fix
    odom1_config: [false, false,  false,
                  false, false, false,
                  true, true, true,
                  false, false, true,
                  false, false, false]
    odom1_queue_size: 10
    odom1_nodelay: true
    odom1_differential: false
    odom1_relative: false
```

I have configured Navsat node for my simulation and your rqt_chart must look like this:

[image]

I hope these modifications help to fix your issue! Good Luck!

Comment: "in addition, you cannot send IMU data twice to the ekf_filter_node_map node(it is being already used when you fused imu+odom in ekf_filter_node_odom)"

Are you saying you cannot fuse imu in both local odometry and global odometry? If so, could you elaborate? Based on robot_localization dual_ekf_navsat_example.yaml example config file they do exactly that.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! We tried your changes, but are still stuck, we tried the odometry/gps, and gps on odom1, and neither seemed to fix it. Any suggestions on next steps to try out?

Comment: Hi Nikolai the output of the first fusion is odom+imu, right? The /odometry/local contains the data from this fusion. This fused t is the input of the next fusion (global), which adds the GPS to the game. So why would you add into/odometry/local (fused imu+odom) the imu again? You must just add the GPS data. At least this is how I've done and worked. @IanWoooood I would suggest getting this example https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_with_gps.html as base, it is very well documented and explains how fusion is done! You can check their GitHub as well.

Comment: Other approach I would try is go step by step to check what is being published and if is being properly consumed by each node:

ros2 topic info /topic_name -v

and 

ros2 node info node_name

As you are using real GPS data, it is possible that the RELIABILiTY is not matching (Reliable vs Best Effort vs Queue_size) did you check it? If not matching you will need to adjust to fit this compatibility